# Make "Show Controls" Checkbox Persistent

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

Can we please make the "show controls" checkbox selection for the winterbash hats persistent? I think most users tend to tweak the position and size of their hats and right now you always have to check the "show controls" box each time you go back to change your hat. It would be nice if the system remembered if you left it checked (or unchecked).

[image]

Comment: Or, if it's too hard to implement, maybe make winterbash persistent.

Comment: Actually, "Show Controls" doesn't need to be enabled to manipulate the hats. They are directly manipulable with the mouse! The checkbox appears to me to be more a "show me how" feature.

Comment: @CodyGray I can't rotate a hat without the controls. Can you?

Comment: Oh. Guess not. Hadn't tried that. Never mind then. :-)